# Regext:Ten digit number whose 4th digit cant be 8 or 9

Tags: regex

How can I create a regex for

A ten digit number whose 4th digit can't be 8 or 9?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should show some effort before posting a question

Answer (score 5):

I think the following regex should do.

```
\d{3}[0-7]\d{6}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like so should work: `^\d{3}[0-7]\d{6}$`:

```
    /^\d{3}[0-7]\d{6}$/
    ^ assert position at start of the string
    \d{3} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: Exactly 3 times
    [0-7] match a single character present in the list below
        0-7 a single character in the range between 0 and 7
    \d{6} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: Exactly 6 times
    $ assert position at end of the string
```